# Calling LayoutInflater's Methods without creating object

Tags: java, android

I am confused with this code[image: Relevant Code]
Here they used and abstract class with inheriting it and most importantly they called a method without creating an object

P.S. Full Code :- https://github.com/udacity/ud839_CustomAdapter_Example/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/flavor/AndroidFlavorAdapter.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were able to call the method without creating an object because the method is *static*. Static methods are not attached to an instance of a class, but rather to the class itself so you can just call them without creating a *new* anything.

For example, if you have

```
public class School {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

to call it you need to create an object, which makes sense, since the method is there to get the name of a particular school.

```
School school = ...;
String schoolName = school.getName();
```

But if you have a static method like this

```
public class School {
    public static List<School> getAllSchools() {
        ....
    }
}
```

then you do not need n instance to call it, because it is not tied to instances, but rather to the class.

```
School.getAllSchools();
```

The same goes for `LayoutInflater.from`. It is not a method to be called from an instance; rather it is a static method that *creates* an instance of LayoutInflater.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

This is called a static initializer, and is used when you want to return an instance of something, but a constructor does not really work. For instance, if you use a constructor (`new LayoutInflater(...)` if that's possible), then it creates a new object every time, which is not always best. But static initializers allow you to create an object and save it so you can return the same object again, which is better in some cases, and is one of the main reasons to use static initializers, like `LayoutInflater.from`.